# Issue with Javascript function

Tags: javascript

I am trying to write a function that will move an element by adjusting its 'left' style over time. Its currently not working at all in its present form.

```
    var tab;
    var tabPos;

    function init() {
        tab = document.getElementById("tab");
        tabPos = 10.8;
        tab.style.left = tabPos + '%';
    }

    function moveOver( ) {
        if (tabPos < 15.8)
            {
                setTimeout(function moveOver( ), 100;
                tabPos = tabPos + 0.1;
                tab.style.left = tabPos + '%';
            }
        else if (tabPos > 15.8)
            {
                setTimeout(function moveOver( ), 100;
                tabPos = tabPos - 0.1;
                tab.style.left = tabPos + '%';
            }
     }
```

The init function successfully sets the initial position of the element but I added the moveOver function to the code the element's position is no longer set.

Comment: You have a syntax error. Should be `setTimeout(moveOver, 100);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the lines:

```
setTimeout(function moveOver( ), 100;
```

to

```
setTimeout(moveOver, 100);
```

---

`function moveOver( )` isn't a valid JavaScript syntax. Also, your brackets (or parenthesis) doesn't match. Because you have a syntax error, your code will not work.

For `setTimeout`, you are supposed to pass a function as the first parameter, so `mouseOver` or `function(){mouseOver();}` will work.

---

Another problem of your script... is that you will see the element constantly jumping.

You have two conditions: `tabpos < 15.8` and `tabpos > 15.8`. The condition which execution doesn't enter either one of both if-blocks is `tabpos == 15.8`... but JavaScript's `Number` is actually a floating point number. Thanks to precision error, `15.8 == 15.7 + 0.1` will result in `false`, which shows that `15.8` is not exactly the same as `15.7 + 0.1`. In fact, `15.7 + 0.1` is *approximately* equal to `15.799999999999999`...

So I suggest you to use an integer value for `tabPos`, for example `158`, and divide it by `10` only when setting the style.

---

A possible result of your code:

```
var tab;
var tabPos;

function init() {
    tab = document.getElementById("tab");
    tabPos = 108;
    tab.style.left = tabPos / 10 + '%';
}

function moveOver( ) {
    if (tabPos < 158)
        {
            setTimeout(moveOver, 100);
            tabPos = tabPos + 1;
            tab.style.left = tabPos / 10 + '%';
        }
    else if (tabPos > 158)
        {
            setTimeout(moveOver, 100);
            tabPos = tabPos - 1;
            tab.style.left = tabPos / 10 + '%';
        }
 }
```

Comment: Yep, the syntax was the main issue and the code works however now that element seems to stutter when it reaches 15.8% instead of stopping.

Comment: This is because you are using `<` and `>` not `<=` or `>=`

Comment: @bearsquared I've expanded my answer, perhaps you would wish to review it.

Answer (score 1):

The brackets for your `setTimeout` function calls are not closed:

```
function moveOver( ) {
    if (tabPos < 15.8)
        {
            setTimeout(function moveOver( ), 100;
            tabPos = tabPos + 0.1;
            tab.style.left = tabPos + '%');  // <----
        }
    else if (tabPos > 15.8)
        {
            setTimeout(function moveOver( ), 100;
            tabPos = tabPos - 0.1;
            tab.style.left = tabPos + '%'); // <----
        }

 }
```

You *should* see JavaScript errors being reported by your browser.

Comment: those are not the correct positions to place the closing brackets for this code.

Answer (score 1):

change `setTimeout(function moveOver( ), 100;` to `setTimeout(moveOver, 100);`